# How can I create an fscanf format string to accept white space and comma (,) tokenization

Tags: c, scanf

I've got some analysis code (`myprog`) that sucks in data using the following:

```
 if(5 == fscanf(in, "%s%lf%f%f%f", tag, & sec, & tgt, & s1, & s2))
```

which works just fine.  But in the situation where I've got data files that are separated by commas, I'm currently doing something like:

```
 sed 's/,/ /g' data | myprog
```

*Can I modify the format string in the `fscanf()` function to accept both delimitation formats?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fscanf(in, "%[^, ]%*[, ]%lf%*[, ]%f%*[, ]%f%*[, ]%f", tag, &sec, &tgt, &s1, &s2)
```

Should work?

Comment: Fix the first regex (`%[^,]` should be `%[^, ]`) and I'll vote you up.

I wasn't familiar with the '*' specifier before now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

char tmp;
fscanf(in, "%s%c%lf%c%f%c%f%c%f", tag,  &tmp, & sec,  &tmp,& tgt,  &tmp,& s1, &tmp, & s2)

If you are not going to care what single character delimits your values, just read it and store it in a throw-away variable.

Comment: What if there isn't any spaces?

Comment: I am only assuming that there is a character delimiter from the original question - experimentation is the mother of discovery.